# Japanese characters not supported by rmagick

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, rmagick

I'm tring to build a voucher from template by rmagick, (using utf8 encoding) Below is just a small code snippet

`text.annotate(template, 0, 0, 23, 155, offer_label) {
        self.pointsize = 16
        self.font_weight = BoldWeight
    }`

When i provide offer_label as 安価な価格でホテルを予約 (japanese)
so in the voucher that is created, the offer_label is dispayed as ????????????.
The offer_label is stored correctly in the database

Template code snippet:

```
<html lang="en">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title><%= @from_name %></title>
 <style type="text/css">
a:hover { color: #09F !important; text-decoration: underline !important; }
 </style>
</head>
```

I looked around the suggested questions but no luck.Looking forward for suggestions.

UPDATE:
The label_name is displayed correctly in the browser web pages, this issue only comes in the voucher which is created using rmagick

Comment: What is your runtime environment(OS and its version)? I think this problem is related to some font setting(s)...

Comment: runtime envt is development, OS-ubuntu 10.04 but the same issues comes in windows-7

Comment: It must be because noone else is using Ruby for Japanese text!

Answer (score 0):

1) you should install Japanese font(s) to your runtime environment(s).

you can check this via [Magick.fonts](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/magick.html#fonts) whether you've installed it or not.

2) specify font related attributes.

use [Draw#annotate](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#annotate) and specify font name/font_family name that you'd like to use.

Hope this helps.